# Is Jackson Lake correct in asserting that the Doctor has never been thanked for saving the world?

Tags: doctor-who

From "[The Next Doctor](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/30-14.htm)":

> LAKE: Well, I'd say he used that Dimension vault to transfer the wreckage of the CyberKing into the Time Vortex, there to be harmlessly disintegrated. Oh, I've picked up a lot. Ah, but here. Ladies and gentlemen, I know that man, that Doctor on high. And I know that he has done this deed a thousand times. But not once. No, sir, **not once, not ever, has he ever been thanked.** But no more. For I say to you, on this Christmas morn, bravo, sir! Bravo! Bravo! Bravo, sir!
>
> (Up in the sky, the Doctor hears the cheers and applause, and waves back, ringing the basket's bell.)
>
> LAKE: Bravo, Doctor.

I suspect this statement is not 100% accurate, but oddly enough I can't actually think of a counterexample. Is there one?

I'm excluding times when he's thanked by a specific person, or for saving a specific person; this is about being thanked by a large number of nameless people who probably would've died (or worse) without him.

Comment: I get the impression the people of Christmas thanked him in "Time of the Doctor" but that happened after "The Next Doctor" so it probably doesn't count...

Comment: [This](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=applause+for+doctor+who&oq=applause+for+doctor+who&aqs=chrome..69i57.3597j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=thanks+for+saving+site:http:%2F%2Fwww.chakoteya.net%2Fdoctorwho) might be useful, if you can be bothered to go through them all...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the end of [Planet of the Ood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_of_the_Ood)

> **Ood Sigma:** Take this song with you.
>
> **The Doctor:** We will.
>
> **Donna:** Always.
>
> **Ood Sigma:** And know this, Doctor Donna. You will never be
>   forgotten. Our children will sing of the Doctor Donna. And our
>   childrens’ children. And the wind and the ice and the snow will carry
>   your names forever.

But of course, it's not quite clear if Ood Sigma is here talking about The Doctor and Donna or about the "Doctor-Donna".
And he wasn't saving the world - only a whole species.

Comment: The Doctor-Donna, however, did save all of existence from The Daleks.

Answer (score 5):

In *The Fires of Pompeii* (series 4 episode 2), the Doctor and Donna are venerated as **gods** by at least one family for their actions in saving that family from the destruction of Pompeii;

> (Quintus kneels before the shrine.)
>   QUINTUS: Thank you, household gods. Thank you for everything.
>   (The little altar has a new carving - the Doctor, the Tardis, and Donna.)

[image: shrine]

He also gets a lot of applause upon his arrival at Torchwood in *Army of Ghosts* (series 2 episode 12), but it's not clear what for:

> (The Doctor steps outside and raises his arms. Yvonne runs in on her high heels.)
>   YVONNE: Oh! Oh, how marvellous. Oh, very good. Superb. Happy day.
>   (She starts clapping and the soldiers join in. The Doctor lowers his arms.)
>   DOCTOR: Er, thanks. Nice to meet you. I'm the Doctor.
>   YVONNE: Oh, I should say. Hurray!
>   DOCTOR: You, you've heard of me, then?
>   YVONNE: Well of course we have. And I have to say, if it wasn't for you, none of us would be here. The Doctor and the Tardis.
>   (More applause.)

Comment: And then they confiscate the TARDIS because "If it's alien, it's ours."